# replace values in python dictionary using string variables

Tags: python

I create python dictionaries for each record that I read.Each record will have mutiple fields..I need to replace the values in the dict using string variables.
I have given the example code below.

```
>>> a = 1
>>> dict1 = dict('id':a)
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    dict1 = dict('id':a)
                     ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't quote `id` and use an equal sign:

```
>>> a = 1
>>> dict1 = dict(id=a)
>>> dict1
{'id': 1}
```